# Rendered component doesn't respond to its props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-state

I'm creating React App "similar" to Trello. In the we have projects, projects have boards, boards have columns, columns have tasks and so on. At default only Project, containing bars with its boards names, should be visible - the rest should be hidden. And if you click on a bar with board title - whole content of this board should be visible. Also, when you click on this bar again, it should become hidden again. I hope that's clear.

The problem is, that I have bars with boards names rendered in one component (ProjectView), which contains many child components (Board), and these components finally can render content of every board (BoardView). In ProjectView I've got a map (visibilityMap) that assigns isHidden-boolean to board's name. Corresponding value from this map is passed to props of every Board component, and Board component passes it to BoardView, where it's used to define *hidden* atribute value for a div with content. Also, in ProjectView I've got a function that changes proper boolean value in the map after clicking on a proper board's name. And everything render properly, I can see in logs that after clicking on board-name a specific value in visibilityMap changes, but it doesn't changes visibility of a specific board content.

I've spent many hours on this and tried many strange things, but I've no idea what's wrong. Below I've attached codes of described components and two screenshots - before and after clicking on board-name.

**ProjectView** - almost everything is on *renderBoard*

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Board from "../controllers/Board";
import {PhotoshopPicker} from 'react-color';

require("../../styles/Project.css");
require("../../styles/Board.css");

class ProjectView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            render: false,
            modalShow: false,
            modalAddShow: false,
            modalBoard: "",
            boardName: "",
            boardBackground: "orange",
            newName: "",
            newBackground: "",
            showAddBackground: false,
            showChangeBackground: false,
            pickedBackground: "orange",
            validate: true,
            visibilityMap: new Map()
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    renderBoards = () => {
        if (this.props.boards.length === 0) {
            return (<div className="no-content">Brak board'ów!</div>)
        }

        if (this.state.visibilityMap.size === 0) {
            this.props.boards.map(board => this.state.visibilityMap.set(board.name, true))
        }

        return this.props.boards.map(board =>
            this.renderBoard(board)
        );
    };

    renderModal = (board) => {
        this.setState({
            modalShow: true,
            modalBoard: board,
            newName: board.name,
            newBackground: board.background,
        })
    };

    handleChangeColor = (color) => {
        this.setState({
            pickedBackground: color
        })
    };

    handleCancelColor = () => {
        this.setState({
            showAddBackground: false,
            showChangeBackground: false,
        })
    };

    handleAcceptAddColor = () => {
        const newColor = this.state.pickedBackground.hex;
        this.setState({
            boardBackground: newColor,
            showAddBackground: false
        })
    };

    handleAcceptChangeColor = () => {
        const newColor = this.state.pickedBackground.hex;
        this.setState({
            newBackground: newColor,
            showChangeBackground: false
        })
    };

    renderBoard = (board) => {
        const handleClose = () => {
            this.setState({
                newName: "",
                newBackground: "",
                modalShow: false
            })
        };

        const switchVisibility = () => {
            const oldValue = this.state.visibilityMap.get(board.name)
            this.state.visibilityMap.set(board.name, !oldValue)
        }

        const handleEdit = () => {
            this.props.handleEdit(this.state.modalBoard.name, this.state.newName, this.state.newBackground);
            handleClose();
            this.setState({
                modalBoard: ""
            });
        };

        return (
            <div className="board" style={{backgroundColor: board.background}}>
                <div className="bookmark board-head" onClick={switchVisibility}>
                    {board.name}
                    <Button
                        className="action-button delete"
                        id={board.name}
                        onClick={this.handleDelete}
                        variant="danger"
                    >
                        X
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className="action-button edit"
                        id={board.name}
                        onClick={() => this.renderModal(board)}
                        variant="warning"
                    >
                        O
                    </Button>
                    <Dialog open={this.state.modalShow} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edytuj boarda {this.state.modalBoard.name}</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <TextField
                                autoFocus
                                margin="dense"
                                name="newName"
                                label="Nazwa boarda"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={this.state.newName}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            <div style={{display: "flex", flexFlow: "nowrap row"}}>
                                <Button
                                    variant="light"
                                    onClick={() => this.setState({
                                        showChangeBackground: true,
                                        pickedBackground: this.state.newBackground
                                    })}
                                >
                                    Kolor:
                                </Button>
                                <div className="color-box"
                                     style={{background: this.state.newBackground}}>
                                </div>
                                <Dialog open={this.state.showChangeBackground} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Kolor boarda {board.name}</DialogTitle>
                                    <DialogContent>
                                        <PhotoshopPicker
                                            header="Wybierz kolor"
                                            onAccept={this.handleAcceptChangeColor}
                                            onCancel={this.handleCancelColor}
                                            color={this.state.pickedBackground}
                                            onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeColor}/>
                                    </DialogContent>
                                </Dialog>
                            </div>
                        </DialogContent>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                                Anuluj
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                onClick={handleEdit}
                                disabled={this.state.newName === "" || !this.state.validate}
                                color="primary">
                                Zapisz
                            </Button>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                </div>
                <Board isHidden={this.state.visibilityMap.get(board.name)} boardReference={board.ref}
                       name={board.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    };

    renderAddModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            modalAddShow: true,
        })
    };

    renderAddBoard = () => {
        const handleClose = () => {
            this.setState({
                modalAddShow: false,
                newName: ""
            })
        };

        const handleAdd = () => {
            this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.boardName, this.state.boardBackground);
            this.setState({boardName: "", boardBackground: "orange"});
            handleClose();
            this.setState({
                modalBoard: ""
            });
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    className="add-button new-board"
                    onClick={this.renderAddModal}
                    variant="success"
                >
                    +
                </Button>
                <Dialog open={this.state.modalAddShow} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Dodaj board'a</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            name="boardName"
                            label="Nazwa"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.boardName}
                            fullWidth
                        >
                        </TextField>
                        <div style={{display: "flex", flexFlow: "nowrap row"}}>
                            <Button
                                margin="dense"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="light"
                                onClick={() => this.setState({
                                    showAddBackground: true
                                })}
                            >
                                Kolor:
                            </Button>
                            <div className="color-box"
                                 style={{background: this.state.boardBackground}}>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Dialog open={this.state.showAddBackground} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Kolor nowego boarda</DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent>
                                <PhotoshopPicker
                                    header="Wybierz kolor"
                                    onAccept={this.handleAcceptAddColor}
                                    onCancel={this.handleCancelColor}
                                    color={this.state.pickedBackground}
                                    onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeColor}/>
                            </DialogContent>
                        </Dialog>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                            Anuluj
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleAdd}
                                disabled={this.state.boardName === "" || !this.state.validate}
                                color="primary">
                            Dodaj
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    };

    handleDelete = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handleDelete(e.target.id);
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const isValid = this.validator(e.target)
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            validate: isValid
        });
    };

    validator = input => {
        if (input.name === "newName" && this.state.modalBoard.name === input.value)
            return true
        const filter = this.props.boards.find(board =>
            board.name === input.value
        )
        return typeof (filter) === "undefined"
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.setState({render: true})
        }.bind(this), 1000)
    }

    render() {
        let renderContainer = false;
        if (this.state.render) {
            renderContainer =
                <div className="project-body">
                    {this.renderBoards()}
                    {this.renderAddBoard()}
                </div>
        }
        return (
            renderContainer
        )
    }
}

export default ProjectView;
```

**Board** - only takes isHidden from props and pass it to BoardView props

```
import React from 'react';
import BoardView from '../views/BoardView';
import {ColumnService} from '../../services/ColumnService';

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.boardReference = this.props.boardReference;
        this.columnService = new ColumnService();
        this.state = {
            columns: [],
            isHidden: this.props.isHidden
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setDatabaseListener();
    }

    handleSubmit = (columnName, order) => {
        this.columnService.addColumn(columnName, order, this.boardReference);
    }

    handleEdit = (name, newColumnName, newColumnOrder) => {
        this.columnService.editColumn(name, newColumnName, newColumnOrder, this.boardReference);
    }

    handleDelete = data => {
        const name = data.id;
        this.columnService.deleteColumn(name, this.boardReference);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BoardView
                isHidden={this.state.isHidden}
                columns={this.state.columns}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
            />
        )
    }

    setDatabaseListener() {
        this.columnService.columnRef(this.boardReference).onSnapshot(data => {
            const listOfFetchedColumns = [];
            data.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const columnReference = doc.ref;
                const data = doc.data();
                data['ref'] = columnReference;
                listOfFetchedColumns.push(data);
                console.log('fetched columns', data);
            });
            listOfFetchedColumns.sort((a, b) => (a.order > b.order) ? 1 : -1)
            this.setState({
                columns: listOfFetchedColumns
            });
        });
    }
}

export default Board;
```

**BoardView** - most important at the end, at *render*

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Column from "../controllers/Column";

require("../../styles/Board.css");
require("../../styles/Column.css");

class BoardView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            render: false,
            modalShow: false,
            modalAddShow: false,
            modalColumn: "",
            columnName: "",
            columnOrder: "",
            newName: "",
            newOrder: "",
            validate: true,
            hideColumns: true,
            isHidden: this.props.isHidden
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    renderColumns = () => {
        if (this.props.columns.length === 0) {
            return (<div className="no-content">Brak kolumn!</div>)
        }

        return this.props.columns.map(column =>
            this.renderColumn(column)
        );
    };

    renderModal = (column) => {
        this.setState({
            modalShow: true,
            modalColumn: column,
            newName: column.name,
            newOrder: column.order
        })
    };

    renderColumn = (column) => {
        const handleClose = () => {
            this.setState({
                modalShow: false,
                newName: "",
                newOrder: ""
            })
        };

        const handleEdit = () => {
            handleClose();
            this.props.handleEdit(this.state.modalColumn.name, this.state.newName, parseInt(this.state.newOrder));
            this.setState({
                modalColumn: ""
            });
        };

        return (
            <div className="column">
                <div className="bookmark column-head">
                    {column.name}
                    <Button
                        className="action-button delete"
                        id={column.name}
                        onClick={this.handleDelete}
                        variant="danger"
                    >
                        X
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className="action-button edit"
                        id={column.name}
                        onClick={() => this.renderModal(column)}
                        variant="warning"
                    >
                        O
                    </Button>
                    <Dialog open={this.state.modalShow} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edytuj kolumnę {this.state.modalColumn.name}</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <TextField
                                autoFocus
                                margin="dense"
                                name="newName"
                                label="Nazwa kolumny"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={this.state.newName}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            <TextField
                                autoFocus
                                margin="dense"
                                name="newOrder"
                                label="Kolejność kolumny"
                                type="number"
                                min={1}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={this.state.newOrder}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                        </DialogContent>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                                Anuluj
                            </Button>
                            <Button onClick={handleEdit}
                                    disabled={
                                        this.state.newName === "" ||
                                        this.state.newOrder === "" ||
                                        this.state.newOrder < 0 ||
                                        !this.state.validate
                                    }
                                    color="primary">
                                Zapisz
                            </Button>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                </div>
                <Column columnReference={column.ref} name={column.name}/>
            </div>
        )
    };

    renderAddModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            modalAddShow: true,
        })
    };

    renderAddColumn = () => {
        const handleClose = () => {
            this.setState({
                modalAddShow: false,
                newName: ""
            })
        };

        const handleAdd = () => {
            this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.columnName, parseInt(this.state.columnOrder));
            this.setState({columnName: "", columnOrder: ""});
            handleClose();
            this.setState({
                modalColumn: ""
            });
        };

        return (
            <div className="new-column-button-wrapper">
                <Button
                    className="add-button new-column"
                    onClick={this.renderAddModal}
                    variant="success"
                >
                    +
                </Button>
                <Dialog open={this.state.modalAddShow} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Dodaj kolumnę</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            name="columnName"
                            label="Nazwa kolumny"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.columnName}
                            fullWidth
                        >
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            name="columnOrder"
                            label="Kolejność"
                            type="number"
                            min={1}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={this.state.columnOrder}
                            fullWidth
                        >
                        </TextField>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                            Anuluj
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleAdd} disabled={
                            this.state.columnName === "" ||
                            this.state.columnOrder === "" ||
                            this.state.columnOrder < 0 ||
                            !this.state.validate
                        } color="primary">
                            Dodaj
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    };

    handleDelete = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handleDelete(e.target);
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const isValid = this.validator(e.target)
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            validate: isValid
        });
    };

    validator = input => {
        if (input.name === "newName" && this.state.modalColumn.name === input.value)
            return true
        const filter = this.props.columns.find(column =>
            column.name === input.value
        )
        return typeof (filter) === "undefined"
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.setState({render: true})
        }.bind(this), 1000)
    }

    render() {
        let renderContainer = false;
        if (this.state.render) {
            renderContainer =
                <div className="board-body" hidden={this.state.isHidden}>
                    {this.renderColumns()}
                    {this.renderAddColumn()}
                </div>
        }
        return (
            renderContainer
        )
    }

}

export default BoardView;
```

[Board content is visible - click on board-name to hide it...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWUp3.png)

[Board content is hidden - click on board-name to show it...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT4Fj.png)

Grateful for Your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that because you are changing the property on the visibilityMap using the maps setter directly (in your switchVisibility method) instead of setting it using setState it is not re-rendering. React uses setState to know when to check for a change in state, which causes the re-render.

So the prop is changing because you did change it, but React is not re-rendering, because it never noticed that state was ever changed.

I've never used a Map when using javaScript, but I'm assuming you chose that instead of an object because you wanted to index it in order?

If that's so my guess is you need to do something like this in your switchVisibility method:

```
this.setState(state => {
let oldValue = state.visibilityMap.get(board.name)
state.visibilityMap.set(board.name, !oldValue)
return state
 )};
```

This will update the state object to contain the new visibilityMap with the prop updated and React should then re-render.

If this looks like magic to you, the setState method, when you pass it a callback automagically passes the current state to that callBack as an argument. You then can manipulate it and return an object again to update state. Useful for toggling things, or when you need the current state to know how to update a new state.

Comment: Thank You so much! It (with the props-to-state assignments in Board in BoardView removed) do the thing :)